# how to close the hyperlink window?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

i have one problem with my app.Im building an app having navigation controller.when i select a particular row,its related url will be loaded.it is working fine.but how to get back from this view to the previous view?I tried to place a navigation bar top of the view but it is not visible.could u please help me out.....

I placed the following coding in did selectrowmethod

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  //Get the selected country
  NSString *selectedCountry = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  //NSString *url=@"";

  if (indexPath.row==0) {

  //url=@"http://www.osha.gov/dcsp/osp/stateprogs/alaska.html" ;
  //label.text=url;
  NSLog(@"======");
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://labor.state.ak.us/lss/oshhome.htm"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
  // self.label.text=@"url";
  // NSLog(@"++++++:%@",self.label.text);
  //textView.text=@"url";

  }

  else if(indexPath.row==1) {

  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ica.state.az.us/ADOSH/"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

  //url=@"http://www.osha.gov/dcsp/osp/stateprogs/arizona.html";
  }
  else if(indexPath.row==2) {

  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.dir.ca.gov/occupational_safety.html"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

  //url=@"http://www.osha.gov/dcsp/osp/stateprogs/arizona.html";
  }

  else if(indexPath.row==3) {

  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ctdol.state.ct.us/osha/osha.htm"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

  //url=@"http://www.osha.gov/dcsp/osp/stateprogs/arizona.html";
  }
  }

Comment: More people would be willing to help you if use the code-tag for your code.

Comment: What you want to do? [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; will open safari app? I think you need to read UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference.

Comment: sir,what i want to do is,when i select a row its particular url should be opened.thats why i loaded the urls in didselectrow method.I have seen UIApplicatonDelegate Protocol reference.and i found,- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url......is this method helpful?i tried to use this in delegate.but no use.. please tell me where i went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens Safari. You can't go back from there. I suggest you check out [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: sir i wrote the coding in select row method,how can i use webview?i really dont know sir,please help me.i have seen uiapplication protocol reference,- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url......is this method helpful?i tried to use this in delegate.but no use..